# mod_wsg with flask and static files served by apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to setup a apache server with flask apps for APIs.
I want a user accessing mydomain.com to get served the index.html from apache and if making requests to mydomain.com/api flask should serve json.

I can get the index.html just fine but when I visit mydomain.com/api I get 404 not found.

This is my apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName temp.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com

        WSGIDaemonProcess incubator-web user=incubator-web group=www-data home=/var/www/incubator-web threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /api/ /var/www/incubator-web/incubator-web.wsgi
        Alias / /var/www/incubator-web/html/

        <Directory /var/www/incubator-web>
                WSGIProcessGroup incubator-web
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIScriptReloading On
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/incubator-web/logs/error.log

        <Directory /var/www/incubator-web/html>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

and my .wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/incubator-web')
from incubator_web import app as application
```

I'm pretty new to all this so I'm guessing that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
Alias / /var/www/incubator-web/html/
```

add:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/incubator-web/html/
```

Setting `Alias` as `/` hides the WSGI application as `Alias` takes precendence over `WSGIScriptAlias`. `DocumentRoot` is the correct way of specifying the default document directory.

Comment: I think I also had to change `WSGIScriptAlias /api/` to `WSGIScriptAlias /api`. After applying your fix I got an error message in my browser about to many redirects but then I changed the config (removed the trailling slash) restarted apache, reloaded the page and it started working.

Comment: Yeah, I almost said something about that. Whether it causes an issue having the trailing slash depends on the Python web framework being used. Some don't necessarily handle it well. Looks like Flask is one where can't have trailing slash on the mount point for a sub URL.